# Any reasons why to limit direct access to an S3 bucket being used to host a static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, web, amazon-s3

If one is hosting a static website using S3 and Cloudfront, linked with an origin-access-identity policy, are there any good reasons( security-related or otherwise) to disable direct public read-access to the origin S3 bucket?

Comment: also, I guess this goes for type of similar situation even if something other than Cloudfront is being used

Comment: Also, to be more specific, I'm not trying to limit access to any resource within the bucket in any way from cloudfrount

Comment: Perhaps if a website is partially static and partially app-based, it can be served behind a single URL via CloudFront using separate paths, which would fail when accessing directly to the bucket. However, for a fully-static site, probably no reason since the bandwidth costs are similar. CloudFront might be cheaper beyond a certain volume (40 TB).